# Prove triangle inequality

Tags: inequality, optimization, metric-spaces

I want to prove that
$d(x,y) = 1- \sum_i {\min(x_i, y_i)}$ where $\sum_i {x_i} = \sum_i {y_i} =1$
and $\forall i: x_i, y_i \geq 0$ satisfies the triangle inequality.

The domain of $d$ therefore is $\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{X}$ with $\mathcal{X} = \{x | x \in \mathbb{R}^d_{\geq 0}, \sum_{i=1}^d {x_i} = 1 \}$

I am pretty sure, that this is actually the case, but I cant come up with a way to prove it. Might be possible that I am wrong and actually a counter example can be found.

Comment: I don't see how this is elementary set theory, or even set theory to begin with. Is this because everything in mathematics is set theory?

Comment: As I read the question, I am under the impression that a proof has already been discovered, but it is not elegant. Am I right?

Comment: what is the domain of $d$ here?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I believed that "min" is strongly connected to set theory, but honestly I had no idea where to put my question.

Comment: @Tunococ: Hm, no, not really. I will rephrase my question.

Comment: @IttayWeiss: Good question. I will edit my question above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that if $a$ and $b$ are two real numbers, then 
$$\min\{a,b\}=\frac{a+b-|a-b|}2.$$
Consequently, for $x,y\in\mathcal X$, we have 
$$d(x,y)=1-\sum_{j=1}^d\frac{x_j+y_j-|x_j-y_j|}2=\frac 12\sum_{j=1}^d|x_j-y_j|,$$
from which triangle inequality is not hard to show.

Comment: thanks, with the help of the subadditivity of the absolute value it was easy from there!